# How to find intersection between a circle interaction and all Features of all Layers visible on the map inside this Interaction?

Tags: openlayers

I use openlayers 4 and I need to draw a circle and highlight Features inside a circle.
Then i need to put that data in a table.
Does anybody know, please, how to get all that stuff inside a cirle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [this demo](https://rawgit.com/webgeodatavore/ol3-extras-demos/master/select-jsts/select-advanced.html) where I'm using JSTS (a 3rd party library)

There are two things you will need to deal here considering your requirements:

- upgrade the code to OpenLayers 4 (demo uses OpenLayers 3.14) but no/minor changes are required
- adapt the code to query more than one layer (the example is using only one layer)

To transform content from features to a table, you will need to make a loop using `select.getFeatures().getArray()` as an input and get features properties this way.

Comment: Thomas, thank you very much for your demo! It really was very useful to understand, how it looks like. But i have another problem now - while i redirect to your demo, there is no code above. And all the code from browser is obfuscated. Where can I look at your code example, if you don`t mind?

Comment: The sample is unobfuscated. If there is some code obfuscated, it comes either from compacted JSTS or OpenLayers libraries (and it's normal, you do not need them unobfuscated). To see the related code you need to understand, a simple right click with "Show source" on the provided page and look at block `<script>` folllowed by `var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({`... It's  where things happen.